# my marker don't show exact address

Tags: android

i have a problem with my marker, i add a map on my app, with marker, when i press marker it gives me this "android.widget.EditText{42b8d740 VFED..CL......ID.." now ill show u the code i use on it:

```
private EditText klienti;
private EditText adresa;

public void initMap(){

    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(lati, longi), 13);
    maps.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
    MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions();
    marker.title(String.valueOf(klienti));
    marker.snippet(String.valueOf(adresa));
    marker.draggable(false);
    marker.position(new LatLng(lati, longi));
    maps.addMarker(marker);
}
```

both "klienti" and "adresa" taken by webservice, when the app is open, the marker goes to the exact address but when i press marker is the problem

Thank You

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: it doesn't show the address and the name of client, it give me this "android.widget.EditText{42b8d740 VFED..CL......ID.."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using as follows

```
marker.title(String.valueOf(klienti));
marker.snippet(String.valueOf(adresa));
```

Which will not give you the value, or content of klienti field. Instead use as follows.

```
marker.title(klienti.getText());
marker.snippet(adresa.getText());
```